# What does xt_tis do?

Tags: stata

While I was trying to understand an `ado` file in Stata, i came across the following command:

```
xt_tis `t'
```

I have tried `help xt_tis`, `findit xt_tis` and even `search xt_tis, net`, but I got nothing helpful.

I would appreciate it if someone could offer me a description of this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Undocumented [`xt`](https://www.stata.com/manuals/xt.pdf#xtxt) command

Syntax:

> xt_tis *varname*

This command saves the name of a *time variable*:

- as a dataset [characteristic](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u12.pdf#u12.8): `_dta[tis]`
- as an s-class [stored result](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rstoredresults.pdf): `s(timevar)`
- in a global [macro](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pmacro.pdf): `S_1`

Comment: Could you please tell me where do you get these information? So I can learn it myself next time when I come across a new command.

Comment: Get it! Thank you :)

Comment: `which xt_tis` tells you it's ado code and `viewsource xt_tis.ado` takes you there.